# How can I animate a TextBlock in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

Hear I'm Binding Some `ObservableCollection` Data to My textblock with Some Time Gap
I'm Displaying data without any Animation,
but I need to Animation to display.
Here is my code:

```cs
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }

    public Slideshow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
        DataContext = App.ViewModel;
        this.Items = App.ViewModel.Items;       
    }

    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        itemNumber = 0;
        Name.Text = this.Items[itemNumber].LineOne;
        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        itemNumber++;
        timer.Start();  
    }

    public void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            itemNumber++;
            Name.Text = this.Items[itemNumber].LineOne;
            if (itemNumber == this.Items.Count)
                itemNumber = 0;
        }

    }
```

XAML Code

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="Name" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding LineOne}"/>
```

How can I do it.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: How do you want to animate it?

Comment: I want to Animate TextBlock Look like a Live tile Animation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `StoryBoard` to animate `TextBlock` Text. What kind of animation you want to use is depend on you. Here I'm demonstrating fading animation of text. By setting its Opacity from 0 to 1 and vice versa.

In XAML,

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <TextBlock Name="TextBlockName" Text="Hello" FontSize="25"/>
    </Grid>
```

add StoryBoard in the Resources

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="StoryBoard1">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlockName"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:1"
                             Completed="DoubleAnimation_Completed_1"/>
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Name="StoryBoard2">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlockName"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

In C#, When ever you want to change the text in `TextBlock`, call the following before setting new text.

```
    StoryBoard1.Begin();
```

and on completion of the above method

```
    private void DoubleAnimation_Completed_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Change the text here before beginning of storyboard2
        TextBlockName.Text = "ABCD";
        StoryBoard2.Begin();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Amit Kumar Code is Very Useful to me But its Not giving Live tile feel how can i improve this code to Look like Live tile. this My first Post what im Exactly Looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313307/tile-animation-in-windows-phone-inside-the-app

Comment: Have you ever look at HubTile feature of Windows Phone toolkit?

Comment: In that post i didn't post any code But My requirement is Live tiles inside the app But using Hub tiles I can't add all My data to that Single tile so i am going with this Text block Animation

Comment: Ok this is what you have to explain in question, it will helps you a lot. that why you need textblock animation and hubtile feature etc. etc.

Comment: I'm reviewing the hubtile code to make it better for you. get back to you soon.

Comment: Have a look at this [sample at MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Windows-Phone-XAML-Create-3707b497)

Comment: I seen this sample 5-6 Mnth's Ago ..But didn't check with this Project ..Let Me check

Comment: It contains Grids and textBoxes which gives feels like LiveTiles, Exactly what you want